# Grafana alert flapping at specific interval

Tags: kubernetes, alert, grafana, prometheus, grafana-alerts

I created an alert for my prometheus data that is flapping every 30 seconds, which is the specified interval I set to check. I’m trying to check if the desired number of pods doesn’t equal the number of available pods in my k8s cluster for an entire 15 minute period. The alert appears to be stating that the metric I specified is the value it was when it last alerted, but if I click “test alert”, the json returned specifies that there shouldn’t be an alert right now. I’m not sure why this is flapping, and any insight would be greatly appreciated. Here’s the relevant info:

Alert Query:`(sum(kube_deployment_spec_replicas{namespace="default"}) without (deployment, instance, pod)) - (sum(kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{namespace="default"}) without (deployment, instance, pod))`

Condtion: `WHEN min() OF query(G,15m,now) IS ABOVE 0.5`

If no data or all values are null set state to Ok

If execution error or timeout set state to keep last state

Edit: When I run the query directly against prometheus, I get the following response:

`curl -k -s 'https://prometheus-k8s/api/v1/query?query=(sum(kube_deployment_spec_replicas%7Bnamespace%3D%22default%22%7D)%20without%20(deployment%2C%20instance%2C%20pod))%20-%20(sum(kube_deployment_status_replicas_available%7Bnamespace%3D%22default%22%7D)%20without%20(deployment%2C%20instance%2C%20pod))'`

`{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[{"metric":{"endpoint":"https-main","job":"kube-state-metrics","namespace":"default","service":"kube-state-metrics"},"value":[1529946877.247,"0"]}]}}%`

Comment: what version of prometheus are you useing?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. It's prometheus 2.3.1, alertmanager 0.14.0

Comment: @JonAumann could you please try to run this query manually once per 2 seconds for 2 minutes and provide us the result?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I ran the query directly against prometheus every 2 seconds for 2 minutes and all I got back was a variation on the response I edit the post with above, with the only thing changing being the timestamp value

Comment: @JonAumann please try to collect the data not from "now", but 1 minute earlier, and check if flipping exists.